# What are differences between Bundle and JSONObject in Android development?

Tags: android, json, bundle

We can use [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) or [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) data structures for to store key-value pairs in the apps.

Also we can use [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) for to store key-value pairs in the apps.

So, what are differences between their?

Is there any advantage/disadvantage of using any one instead of the other one?

Comment: They have quite different use cases... How do you pass data between Intents without a Bundle? How do you parse JSON with only a Bundle? Also, JSONArray doesn't store key-value pairs.

Comment: `Bundle` is what you can use for **both inner or inter app** communication but `Json` is not!

Comment: Here is an easy example; Bundle is like a Gift box, it has weight (little bit heavy) and can hold any content like chocolates and stuffs, while JSONObject/Array were just a piece of paper that can hold text like love letter, Unlike the bundle the JSON thing is much lighter.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen. But I cannot understand why negative reputation is given to the question. The reference pages don't include these information and stack doesn't have the similar question. Also I'm a newbie to Android development :) Anyway..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android, Bundle is associated with fragment/activity/Service/BroadcastReceiver. It is used to send data from one activity/fragment to another. we can send data through JSONObject too but we need medium to transfer data either common filesystem or local db or bundle. Bundle is a key value pair data structure as well as a medium. 
JSONObject is mostly used in web apis and to serialize Objects.

Answer (score 1):

The are used in different cases. **Bundle** is used to transfer data between Activities, while **JSONObject** is used to contain JSON data and manipulate that same data. You can not pass directly a JSONObject to Activity, thus you need to us a Bundle.